# Importing live website to Localhost

Tags: import, amazon-ec2, localhost

I am using Amazon EC2 instance for my website which is live right now.

I am struggling to import the latest version of live website onto my local server. I archived the website & downloaded, downloaded the db & after extracting to 'www/' in localhost & then creating & importing the db, the localhost does not load up the website. On the localhost page, it changes the path to 'restricted page', yet doesnt even show (load) the restricted page.

What is the best way of importing live website from EC2 to localhost?

Comment: Really, it would help if you showed more, like your server configuration, what type of server you're using, like Apache for instance, and what you've tried so far. This will help people who want to help you not have to start from scratch. Hope this helps!

Comment: This sounds more like an Apache problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, the db was corrupt. We had to extract the data & recreate the whole site by installing everything one by one.